# How to continuously build and release IPA files for testing

Tags: ios, build

In my project I have to build an IPA file ASAP after developer committed the changes to TFS and then I have to test the IPA file which I have built.

To do that I have to build the project by "`Ionic Build IOS`", then open it using Xcode, and then have to archive.

Only then I can get the IPA file.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I edit your question a bit to clean it up. Check the edits and next time try it writing it that way yourself - you have enough XP points to know your way better, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to go into specifics because that is largely dependent on what tools you use. I use the Atlassian suite of products.

We build an IPA file when new code is merged into a specific branch. This is done using Bamboo (although any CI tool should be able to do it) that gets triggered by a BitBucket trigger. The trigger fires off a Bamboo Plan on a Mac Bamboo Agent to do a Git Pull and then Xcode build (via command line). The last step is copying the IPA from the Mac to our network share.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all developer tool steps have command-line alternatives. There should not be a need to use the actual GUI to build a piece of software.

Research how you can do this with the command line and then you can configure your [CI-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) todo the same.

Google is full of links on this search query "build ipa file from command line":

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line

or something like "build ipa file from ci":

- https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/